# React Router v4 nested routes props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm updating my universal react redux app to use react router v4. I have nested routes under a main layout route. Previously I used {props.children} to show contents of child routes, but this doesn't work anymore. How does this work in V4?

```
<Provider store={store} key="provider">
  <div>
    <Route component={Layout} />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route component={Error404} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Provider>
```

or

```
<Provider store={store} key="provider">
  <Layout>
    <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route component={Error404} />
  </Layout>
</Provider>
```

This is how my Layout file looks

```
const Layout = props => (
 <div className="o-container">
   <Header />
     <main>
      {props.children}
     </main>
   <Footer />
 </div>
);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have taken the `<Provider>`out because it belongs to `react-redux` and you don't need it as basis for routing with `react-router` (anyway you can easily add it encapsulating the structure with it).

In React Router V4, what was `Router` has been renamed to `BrowserRouter` and imported from package `react-router-dom`. So for nesting routes you need to insert this as children of your `<Layout>`.

index.js

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './Layout';
...
const Root = () => (
  <Layout>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/other" component={OtherComponent} />
        <Route component={Error404} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Layout>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Layout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';

const Layout = props => ({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="o-container">
        <Header />
        <main>{props.children}</main>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default Layout;
```

Take in count this only works for web. Native implementation differs.
I uploaded [a small project](https://github.com/p-fernandez/react-router-v4-nestedroutes-example) based in Create React App where I show the implementation of nested routes in V4.

Comment: Thanks the the reply @Dez, ive changed my structure. Part of the problem is that its a univeral app, all the routes then need to be in <StaticRouter>, aswell as <BrowserRouter> for client. Im still getting a error on the server when I include Link from react-router-dom

Comment: @blamb as it has been said in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44799564/305953 of this same question,  `IndexRoute` is not available anymore in React Router 4. You have the RR4 documentation here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy

Comment: @Dez Sorry had to remove comment to update it, didnt notice you had answered it was hidden. 
I cant get children routes to work the old way without using a parent div, and using this `<Route path="/" component={Layout}>` and `<IndexRoute component={Home}/>`   inside `</BrowserRouter>`, with or without a wrapping div.  I want a layout to load, and the route to load inside the layout for a given route.  The documentation isn't clear to me, about this part.  Is there more documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 17):

Just thought I have to share this. If you're using a `Link` component in your `Header` component. The answer above won't work. You would have to make the `BrowserRouter` as the parent again to support `Link`. Make it like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Layout>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/other" component={OtherComponent} />
    <Route component={Error404} />
  </Switch>
 </Layout>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This is a good point to anyone finding problems if they try that. OP at first just meant to load routes as children of his layout.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this structure, without props.children :

```
const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route component={Error404} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

const Layout = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Main />
    <Footer />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout />
      </BrowserRouter>
   </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read this blog through. https://codeburst.io/react-router-v4-unofficial-migration-guide-5a370b8905a

> #### No More `<IndexRoute>`
>
> The  component allowed to route to a certain component on a top-level path in v3:

```
// in src/MyApp.js
const MyApp = () => (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/foo" component={Foo} />
            <Route path="/bar" component={Bar} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
)
```

> This component doesn’t exist anymore in v4. To replace it, use a combination of , exact, and route ordering (placing the index route last):

```
  // in src/MyApp.js
const MyApp = () => {
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout} />
    </Router>
}
// in src/Layout.js
const Layout = () => (
    <div className="body">
        <h1 className="title">MyApp</h1>
        <div className="content">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/foo" component={Foo} />
                <Route exact path="/bar" component={Bar} />
                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: If the index route is using exact, then why would you place it last?

Comment: It doesn’t matter if it is placed last or first IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Dez answer

Complete native / core implementation with Redux support

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import createMemoryHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory';

const history = createMemoryHistory();

import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </App>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({appName: state.appName});

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <Header appName={this.props.appName} /> {/*common header*/}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, () => ({}))(App);
```

Answer (score -1):

If using with Redux, without the Switch element

AppRouter.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'



const AppRouter = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Layout>
)

export default AppRouter;
```

Layout.js

```
const Layout = props => ({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <main>{props.children}</main>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default Layout;
```

Provider placed in Render function

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';


import AppRouter from './AppRouter';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <AppRouter />
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('app'));
```